# How to move users from third-party app to play store listed app?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am planning to roll out the APK to a closed set of users (basically friends and family) to let them play around with the app and suggest improvements/changes etc.

Once done with debugging, I would like to list the app on Play Store, so that these closed set of users who already have the app installed can just update it. Is that possible?

There are few user-specific data that I am storing and I do not want these users to lose that data! That would be disastrous! Would simply keeping the package name as same allow these users to update the app?

I am worried that since Play Store does not know about these users, they may see the "Install" button on play store listing instead of "Update" button.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play has an alpha and beta channel.  It seems like this is the perfect use-case scenario for it.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that need creating a google group or something? Because I want to let these early users forward the apk to other users as well, the condition for having a Google group can be a roadblock!

Comment: It can be an open group or a Google+ community. It's basically 3 steps.  Here's Facebook's example.

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/introducing-the-facebook-for-android-beta-testing-program/10151529228878920

Honestly, if I was beta testing something, I'd much rather get it from Google Play that's attached to a dev account than some APK a friend of a friend sent me.

Comment: Ok, read the post and it seems doable. I will mark the answer correct for now... thanks a ton!